# How to do my table to link dropdown list month and year separately

Tags: excel

I having one table that table I need to enter value each and every month .
at the same time if I want to check last month Click last month what I entered value should come
IF want add value for next month when I click next month that table should come without value
That table should come separately in every month

Eg: 2023
Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, may till Dec

I tried dropdown list with Hyper link to my excel sheet

Comment: I think you're getting no responses because your question is quite unclear.  I suggest you break the question into clear sentences to start with.  Next give a good example of your starting table and then, separately, the end goal.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.